# how to loop over files with no extensions in makefile

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

Hello im trying to iterate over files with no extension in a directory in my makefile. My current code looks like this:

```
for F in test/*; do echo $$F; done;
```

How do I edit this to be able to iterate only through files with no extensions?

Answer (score 0):

You could test for the dot in the file name, e.g.

```
target:
        for F in test/*; do \
          case $$F in \
            (*.*) echo ignore;; \
            (*)   echo $$F;; \
          esac; \
        done
```

Comment: im having some problems with the syntax do i use double space like you or tab?

Comment: @saxenm2 In make rules you must use one initial tab, then spaces or tabs.

Comment: im trying the following code:
for FILE in testing/*; do \
               case $$FILE in /
                       (*.*) echo ignore;; \
                       (*) echo $$FILE;; \
               esac;
       done

Comment: it says unexpected end of file

Comment: @saxenm2 You've got a slash after `in` which should be a backslash. The Makefile I wrote works here.